# Disable native iOS smart banner

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, safari

I'm using the smart banner jQuery plugin for showing different apps depending on the part of the web the user is in android and iOS.

The problem is that Safari loads the native banner from the line:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=xxxxxxxxxx">
```

So I'm showing 2 banners in Safari.

How can I disable the native Safari banner or hide it with CSS? 
I tried removing that line of code but then both banners are not shown.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this yet?

Answer (score 0):

To hide some component You can simple use `display:none` if You have id of this second element

Comment: Sure, I have the id of the second smart banner (the one I created manually with the jquery plugin) but I don't know wich id is using the native smart banner. I want to hide the native banner (and I can't acces to it inspecting the element because it's only shown in my iPhone)

Answer (score 0):

It's a rather common problem.

As an alternative you could use [smartbanner.js](https://github.com/ain/smartbanner.js) that does the same job without any external dependencies, e.g. Apple's native meta tags or jQuery.